# How to find faster in linux

Tags: linux, find, aix

I have some directory with funny character such as ^M at their back. They were created accidentally and I want to delete them.

I list the directories by `ls -iql` and wrote down their inode number, then I try to delete it by searching it by inode number.

```
find . -inum 7990028 -exec rmdir -i {} \;
```

But the command is so slow. I got only some hundreds of directories, but there are a lot of files inside the directories. I think the find command must have been searching through the files.

How can I improve this?

Comment: also the command fail to delte the directory.......how can I get it right?

Comment: Why are you looking for directories by inode?

Comment: Because I don't know what are the funny character. It is invisible when I just "ls", and become "?" when I "ls -q". But it is not "?".

Comment: pipe the output of ls through 'cat -v' or 'cat -A' to have it show you what the 'funny characters' are.   From your example though, they're Carriage Returns (^M).  Could remove all with 'rm -rf "*{CTRL-V}{CTRL-M}"'.   But I'd run that as 'ls "*{CTRL-V}{CTRL-M}"' first just to check things.   '-rf' is VERY powerful (aka dangerous)

Answer (score 1):

The . in the command means "search from the current directory".  So to make it fast, you should be in the directory above the directory you want to delete.  You can then also limit the search depth to the current directory, and also limit by directories only:

```
find . -inum 7990028 -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec rmdir -i {} \;
```

Comment: aix doesnot have maxdepth option. I already at the directory above the directories. PS. aix have -depth option, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, aix.  Ok, well the ```-type d``` will make a big difference.

Comment: It's still very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the problematic characters are non-printable, you can simply use

```
rm -rf *[^[:print:]]*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much easier just to delete all filenames that contain the `^M` in them than to, well... find.

> `rm -rf *`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>`*`

Comment: actually I don't what the character is. When I do "ls -q", they have "?" at their back, and I tried "?" already.

Comment: Does your shell have auto-complete?  Can you just use tab to complete the directory name?

Comment: @gunbuster363: So then use a range instead. `*[`Ctrl-V Ctrl-A Ctrl-V Ctrl-B ... Ctrl-V Ctrl-]`]*`

Comment: Recommend quoting that, since an errant space can ruin your day.